# Pagination outside of channel entries tag?

Tags: pagination

I have a channel entries loop that I need to paginate but am having an issue with the location of the pagination code.

The channel entries loop surrounds a table structure but is inside the main table tags as to not repeat them.

The pagination code needs to be outside of the main table tags.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure - something like this (simplified obviously):

```
{exp:channel:entries paginate="bottom"}
    {if count == "1"}<table>{/if}
        <tr>
            <td>{content}</td>
        </tr>
    {if count == total_results}</table>{/if}
    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
{/exo:channel:entries}
```

In this case, your pagination links should appear after your table closes.