# paginate not displaying next enties

Tags: pagination

I am having and issue with pagination.  I have 8 entries and displaying 4 per page.  Because of the layout I cannot include the pagination in the first channel entries tag that displays the entries so I need to add a second channel entries tag just for the pagination.  Problem is when I click the next page and display the next 4 entries I still get the same first 4 entries.

```
<div class="blog">
        <h4 class="heading colr">Messages</h4>
        <ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="messages" limit="4" dynamic="yes" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields"}

            <li>
                <p class="date">{entry_date format="%M"}<br />{entry_date format="%d"}</p>
                <h2 class="colr">{title}</h2>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="cont">

                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="blog_links">

                    <p class="postedby">Speaker: {speaker}</p>
                </div> 
            </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}

                     </ul>
    </div>


{exp:channel:entries channel="messages" limit="4" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields" paginate="bottom"}
    {paginate}
        {pagination_links}
    <ul>
            {first_page}
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
            {/first_page}

            {previous_page}
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous"><</a></li>
            {/previous_page}

            {page}
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
            {/page}

            {next_page}
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">></a></li>
            {/next_page}

            {last_page}
                    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
            {/last_page}
    </ul>
        {/pagination_links}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: this helped: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/pagination-outside-of-channel-entries-tag

Comment: "this helped" - does that mean you've solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't work because the channel:entries tag relies on the paginate parameter. If you don't include it EE won't read the pagination segment in the URL, so won't know you're on the second page of a paginated list.

Assuming the issue is your markup and you only want to close the list markup before you open the pagination elements markup, try this:

```
<div class="blog">
  <h4 class="heading colr">Messages</h4>
  <ul>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="messages" limit="4" dynamic="yes" paginate="bottom" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields"}

      <li>
        <p class="date">{entry_date format="%M"}<br />{entry_date format="%d"}</p>
        <h2 class="colr">{title}</h2>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="cont"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="blog_links">
            <p class="postedby">Speaker: {speaker}</p>
        </div> 
      </li>
    {if count == total_results}
  </ul>
</div>
    {/if}

{paginate}
  {pagination_links}
  <ul>
    {first_page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
    {/first_page}
    {previous_page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous"><</a></li>
    {/previous_page}
    {page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
    {/page}
    {next_page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">></a></li>
    {/next_page}
    {last_page}
      <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
    {/last_page}
  </ul>
  {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Note the:

```
{if count == total_results}
    </ul>
  </div>
{/if}
```